# JSON data parsing in Django AJAX POST Request

Tags: python, jquery, json, ajax, django

I'm getting below error whenever I send a JSON object via AJAX post request in Django.

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

**Code in html:**

```
 $("#submit").click(function(){

           var finalData{};
           finalData.name = $('#name').val();
           finalData.email = $('#email').val();
           finalData.password = $('#password').val();
           finalData.website = $('#website').val();

           $.ajax({

                  url: window.location.pathname,
                  type: "POST",
                  data :finalData,
                  success: function(){

                  },
                  error: function(){

                  }
                });

            });
    });



    <form  method = "POST" >
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" name="name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Website:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="website" placeholder="Enter website" name="website">
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

**Code in Python:**

```
def signup(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    body = request.body
    response_json = body.decode('utf-8')
    x = json.loads(response_json)
    print(x)

    return render(request, 'signup.html', {})

else:
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {})
```

I'm able to print the response using below command in Python

```
print(request.body)
```

**Sample JSON Data Object:**

```
{
   name: test,
   email: test@gmail.com,
   password: test,
   website: www.test.com
}
```

What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: try this  `data: JSON.stringify(finalData)`, `contentType: "application/json",`

Comment: @Macintosh_89 tried after adding  dataType: "json". But I'm getting same error.

Comment: i have edited my answer

Comment: @Macintosh_89 tried edited code, that didn't work either.

Comment: Your actual code works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone else posted the answer and deleted it. It actually worked for me.

Here is the code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   response_json = request.POST
   response_json = json.dumps(response_json)
   data = json.loads(response_json)
   print(data)
```

Comment: I believe that request.POST only applies to conventional html form data, so this won't work with AJAX. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST